# Thermodynamic relation $p$ for a paramagnetic system

Tags: thermodynamics, magnetic-fields, pressure, magnetic-moment

I am currently reading up on magnetic systems and the author made mention of the relation to a thermodynamic variable, the pressure.

The pressure $p$ for a system is

$$p = -(\frac{\partial F}{\partial V})|_{T,N}.$$

For a paramagnetic system, the total magnetic moment $\vec{m} = \sum_{i=1}^{N}\vec{\mu_{i}}$ of a system replaces $p$ and $-(\frac{\partial F}{\partial \vec{B}_{ext}} )|_{T,N}$ replaces $-(\frac{\partial F}{\partial V})|_{T,N}$

where $\vec{B}_{ext}$ is the external magnetic field applied to the system, $\vec{\mu}$ the individual magnetic dipole moment in this paramagnetic system, $T$ the temperature, $N$ the number of electrons, $V$ the volume and $F$ is the Helmholtz free energy.

How should I better understand this *replacement* that the author speaks of? (I haven't been able to find any resources on an explanation behind this *replacement*)

Comment: for an excellent discussion read Reif chapter 11.1 in https://archive.org/details/fundamentalsofst00reif/page/n15/mode/2up or Callen Appendix B in https://archive.org/details/thermodynamicsan0000call

Comment: @hyportnex Wholesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most generally, we can write for any closed (constant-$N$) system the expressions

$$dU=\delta Q+\delta W;$$

$$dU=T\,dS+\sum_j X_j\,dY_j;$$

that is, we can increase the energy $U$ through heating ($\delta Q$) or through work ($\delta W$).

The second equation, called the [fundamental relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_thermodynamic_relation), uses state variables to express the heating ($T\,dS$, with temperature $T$ and entropy $S$) and work ($\sum_j X_j\,dY_j$, where $X$ and $Y$ are respectively generic [intensive and extensive conjugate variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_variables_(thermodynamics)) and $j$ indexes all the relevant types of work).

The classic placeholder for work is so-called pressure–volume work ($-P\,dV$), where the anomalous minus sign arises because pressure corresponds to negative stress. But many other flavors of work are possible, such as magnetic work $\vec{m}\,d\vec{B}_\text{ext}$, corresponding to the following fundamental relation:

$$dU=T\,dS-P\,dV+\vec{m}\,d\vec{B}_\text{ext}.$$

For convenience, let's apply a Legendre transform ($F\equiv U-TS$) to use the [Helmholtz free energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_free_energy) to obtain $T$ as a natural variable:

$$dF=-S\,dT-P\,dV+\vec{m}\,d\vec{B}_\text{ext}.$$

The pressure and magnetic moment are thus defined as

$$P\equiv-\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial V}\right)_{T,\vec{B}_\text{ext},N};$$

$$\vec{m}\equiv\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial \vec{B}_\text{ext}}\right)_{T,V,N},$$

respectively. Does this get at what you're asking about?

Comment: One question for clarity and for cementing my knowledge:

Thank you.

From what you've written, am I understanding correctly that any work done on (or by) a thermodynamic system can be expressed as the sum of the multiplicative product of any two conjugate variables?

Comment: Yes, that's the general framework. A gradient in the intensive variable (e.g., pressure) drives a shift in the extensive variable (in this case, volume). The units always multiply to give units of energy.

Comment: so in your expression for dU, is the magnetic field an independent variable of the internal energy?

Comment: Not necessarily, no. The intensive  variables are generally a function of the internal energy.